# Given two intervals find all non-overlapping intervals

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two intervals A = [1, 10] and B = [3, 7]. Return all non-overlapping intervals, so the result would be [1, 2] and [8, 10]

Assume that there is always an overlap between A and B.

I tried splitting the problem into cases:
Suppose you want to find non-overlapping intervals between A and B.

```
Case 1:
  A = [0, 5] and B = [2, 3]. 
  The result would be [0, 1] and [4, 5]. 
  General case: 
    if A[0] < B[0] and B[1] < A[1] 
    then [A[0], B[0] - 1] and [B[1] + 1, A[1]]

Case 2:
  A = [0, 5] and B = [0, 5].
  The result would be [].
  General case: 
    if A[0] == B[0] and B[1] == A[1] 
    then []

                      .
                      .
                      .
```

I continued to make 4 other cases. But this seems a bit too tedious. Is there an easier implementation to this?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the list also contain interval `[6, 6]`, i.e. the non-overlapping part of `[2, 8]`? Or _would_ it contain this if it weren't zero-length?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Will there be any cases like independent intervals. For eg: A = [1, 10] and B= [15, 20] ? Otherwise, will B always be a subset of A?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "interval algebra", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: @BishalG I am assuming there always will be an overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand correctly input will contain two intervals say `A` and `B` and we have to find all linear subsegments which is not shared by both intervals.

We may observe that there will be at max `2` intervals as solution. We can print solution by checking following conditions:

```
if (A[0] > B[1] || B[0] > A[1]) { // for non-intersecting independent intervals
     print: {A[0], A[1]} and {B[0], B[1]}
} else {
  if (A[0] != B[0]) {
     print: {min(A[0], B[0]), max(A[0], B[0]) - 1}
  }
  if (A[1] != B[1]) {
     print: {min(A[1], B[1]) + 1, max(A[1], B[1])}
  } 
}
```

Comment: Great solution, I am doing to test in out

Answer (score 0):

Convert your input to the following format by placing all events on one linear timeline and sorting it in the ascending order:

- interval starts on 1
- interval starts on 3
- interval ends on 7
- interval ends on 10

Then, go through the timeline and count the balance of intervals by incrementing on "start" and decrementing on "ends".

Now, the task can be rephrased as "output all intervals where balance is equal to 1", because when you have balance equal to 1, then it means that there is exactly one non-overlapping interval.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the term 'balance of intervals' mean?

Comment: @hammerhead Number of started intervals minus number of ended intervals. So, go through the timeline and increase balance by 1 when you meet a start of an interval, and decrease by 1 when you meet an end.